# OLE initialization failed - MFC Visual Studio 2010 Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, mfc, ole

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution for an MFC application that used to run just fine on my Windows 7 machine. Today when I tried to run it, although it still compiles successfully, it gives me the following error on launch:

> OLE initialization failed. Make sure that the OLE libraries are the
>   correct version.

Then the application closes. After some debugging, I found that the error occurs inside AfxOleInit as a result of the call to OleInitialize (return value RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE).

This application was actually provided to us by one of our vendors - so I did not write the code, and I personally have very little experience with MFC. What has me stumped is that the source code has not changed since the last time I ran it on this same machine (which was months ago). The only thing I can think of is that I have installed Visual Studio 2012 (alongside 2010) on this PC since the last time I successfully ran this application - could this have indirectly messed up references or DLL versions?

After spending some time Google searching for a solution and coming up with nothing, I am turning to you for any tips or suggestions you may have. Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: This is always a bug, not a "reinstall Windows" kind of problem.  Your program is initializing COM twice with conflicting values for the dwCoInit argument of CoInitializeEx() function.  We can't help you find those calls of course.

Comment: I guess, as a workaround you can modify the program to ignore RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE error after OleInitialize call. I bet it will work fine. Of course you need to find the bugs Hans has pointed to

Comment: Did you try it on another computer ?